# low-level Java-based file repository

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Does anyone know of a library that will help me build a file store in Java?  I am not looking for something like JCP.  Rather, I need to build something that stores millions of files/terabytes of data, de-duped by hash, and with metadata for each file.  Metadata might include mime type, filenames, dates, size, etc.  (A hash might correspond to various filenames, dates, etc.)

I know this is not overly difficult, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if the wheel already exists.  For example, files have to be sorted into a directory hierarchy on disk based on part of the hash to avoid exceeding the maximum number of files the OS will allow per directory.  A web service needs to be written to provide access to files, etc.  Some other data structure (RDBMS?) needs to store the metadata.  A mechanism is needed for loading new content.

Everything I am finding is higher level, JCP or JCP-ish, but I figured it was worth checking with the experts here before going off to build it.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the existing content management solutions are too high level for my purposes.  SQLServer with FILESTREAM is about as close as I could find with what promises to be reasonable performance.  However this is not a difficult thing to build and then I won't have to reply on a specific RDBMS for the solution, so that is the route I'm going to go with.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely don't reinvent the wheel... an RDBMS might work, but something like Apache Rabbit perhaps? If you want reaalllllyyyyy low level there is Peter Lawrey's Chronicle.